# DiffGrams for .NET Core. We are upgrading our project to .NET Core 3.x so need to find the DiffGrams used in the previous version of .NET

Tags: asp.net-core

We are upgrading our .NET 2.0 application to .NET Core 3.x there's a DiffGrams used to capture the Table field updates (before/after values) used for Auditing purpose. I have to achieve the similar in the .NET Core 3.x. I am not sure which one is the equivalent for .NET Core 3.x.

Could you anyone help me guide on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**DataSet.[WriteXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_DataSet_WriteXml_System_IO_Stream_)/DataSet.[ReadXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=netcore-3.1)** method applies to .NET Core 3.x.

The `WriteXml` method provides a way to write either data only, or both data and schema from a DataSet into an XML document.

```
private void WriteXmlToFile(DataSet thisDataSet)
{
    if (thisDataSet == null) { return; }

    // Create a file name to write to.
    string filename = "XmlDoc.xml";

    // Create the FileStream to write with.
    System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream
        (filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

    // Create an XmlTextWriter with the fileStream.
    System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xmlWriter =
        new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(stream,
        System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);

    // Write to the file with the WriteXml method.
    thisDataSet.WriteXml(xmlWriter, XmlWriteMode.DiffGram);
    xmlWriter.Close();
}
```

The resultant XML code is rooted in the `<diffgr:diffgram>` node and contains up to three distinct data sections, as follows:

```
<diffgr:diffgram>
      <MyDataSet>
      :
      </MyDataSet>
      
      <diffgr:before>
      :
      </diffgr:before>
      
      <diffgr:errors>
      :
      </diffgr:errors>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```